# Help in positioning a popup menu in the screen

Tags: macvim, popup-menu

I am using MacVim and I wish a popup menu to always appear in the lower right corner of the screen (not the current window).
I am using the following command:

```
popup_create(items, {
    title: " Title ",
    line: line('$'),
    col: col('$'),
    pos: "botright",
    posinvert: false,
    filter: MyFilter,
    maxheight: &lines - 1,
    })
```

but `line('$')` is the last line of the buffer (not the screen) and the `col('$')` is the last column with respect to the cursor position.

Comment: `:h screenrow()` and `:h sreenpos()` or potentially also `:h winwidth()`

Comment: Thanks! Btw, it seems that I solved with &lines and &columns but I don't know how robust could it be. Shall I write a complete answer if I won't encounter any issues with this solution?

Comment: lines and columns should I think always be set and should be fine as well

Comment: Please write an answer with whatever you come up with

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use `&lines` and `&columns`:

```
popup_create(items, {
    title: " Title ",
    line: &lines,
    col: &columns,
    pos: "botright",
    posinvert: false,
    filter: MyFilter,
    maxheight: &lines - 1,
    })
```